# An analogy to the argument given in the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let us take the interval $(-1,1)$ on $\Bbb{R}$. I will try to prove it is compact:

Let us assume $(-1,1)$ is not compact. This implied it has an infinite cover $\mathfrak{C}$ which does not have a finite subcover. We can select a subset of $(-1,1)$ which is not covered by a finite subset of $\mathfrak{C}$. One such subset is $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

Going like this, we can create nested open sets such that $(a_k,b_k)=(-\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k})$, such that none of these are covered by a finite subcover of $\mathfrak{C}$. The infinite intersection $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{2^i},\frac{1}{2^i})=\{0\}$. As $\mathfrak{C}$ covers the whole of $(-1,1)$, there is an open set $S_1\in\mathfrak{C}$ such that $\{0\}\in S_1$.

We can construct a ball $B(0,\epsilon)\subset S_1$. Also, for a large enough $k$, $(-\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k})\subset B(0,\epsilon)$. This basically implies $(-\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k})\subset S_1$, athough we had assumed $(-\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k})$ cannot be covered by a finite number of sets from $\mathfrak{C}$ for any $k$. This is a contradiction. Hence, $(-1,1)$ is comnpact.

This is analogous to the argument given for the Heine-Borel theorem. I know that $(-1,1)$ is not compact. Any help in understanding the flaw would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why is $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ "one such subset?" Since $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is compact, it has a finite sub-cover, so $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$  does too. Hint: the problem for open intervals is not covering the middle parts...

Comment: The reason for my choosing $(-\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k})$ was I wanted a nonempty infinite intersection, so that I could construct the ball $B(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: I know why you chose it, but you've asserted something that isn't true about it. There is no reason to think, given a cover of $(-1,1)$ with no finite sub-cover, that $\left(-\frac 12,\frac 12\right)$ does not have a finite sub-cover. Indeed, if $-1<a<b<1$ then, given any cover of $(-1,1)$, $(a,b)$ has a finite sub-cover.

Comment: Speaking more generally, taking the open set $(a,b)$, is it never possible to take nested open sets such that each is not covered by a finite subset of $\mathfrak{C}$. the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{diam}(a_n,b_n)=0$, and the infinite intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (a_i,b_i)\neq\emptyset$? BEcause then this argument will hold true. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, no, ignore my previous (now-deleted) comment. If ever $a<a_i<b_i<b$, any open cover of $(a,b)$ has a finite sub-cover of $[a_i,b_i]\subset (a,b)$ by Heine Borel, so the open interval of $(a_i,b_i)$ also has a finite sub-cover. So the only way to get such a sequence is to either have $a_i=a$ for all $i$ and $b_i\to a$, or $b_i=b$ for all $a$ and $a_i\to b$. In that case, $\cap(a_i,b_i)=\emptyset$

Comment: This argument just blew my mind. Thanks tons, really!! Most grateful

Comment: Also, I feel adding this argument to your answer below would answer the question even better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ "one such subset?" Since $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is compact, it has a finite sub-cover, so $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$  does too. The problem for open intervals is not covering the middle parts...

The usual counter-example shows why your proof doesn't work. Let $U_n=\left(-1,1-\frac1n\right)$. Then the $U_i$ cover $(-1,1)$ but don't have a finite sub-cover. Note that $\left(-\frac 12,\frac 12\right)$ has a finite sub-cover. Indeed $U_1$ covers $\left(-\frac 12,\frac 12\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to assert that $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ cannot be covered by a finite subcover of $\mathfrak{C}$.

Comment: I had thought the same. Speaking more generally, taking the open set $(a,b)$, is it never possible to take nested open sets such that each is not covered by a finite subset of $\mathfrak{C}$, the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{diam}(a_n,b_n)=0$, and the infinite intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (a_i,b_i)\neq\emptyset$? Because then this proof will hold true.